# Serializing JSON object error of Generic type

Tags: c#, serialization

I am trying to serialize an object that I have created here:

```
using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(CaseTreatment));
    ser.WriteObject(memStream, ct);
}
```

This is `ct` here: `List<CaseTreatment> ct = new List<CaseTreatment>();`

Whenever my code hits `ser.WriteObject(memStream, ct);` I get the following error:

```
Type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[FileUpload.Models.CaseTreatment, FileUpload,
Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' with data contract name 
'ArrayOfCaseTreatment:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/FileUpload.Models' is 
not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known 
statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute 
attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to 
DataContractSerializer.
```

My `CaseTreatment` object looks like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class CaseTreatment
{
    [DataMember]
    public Bridge BridgeTreatment;
}
```

And `Bridge` looks like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Bridge : CaseGeneric
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool IsBridgeTreatment;

    public Bridge(XElement treatment, IEnumerable<XElement> orderDetails)
    {
        var tn = Util.GetTitle(treatment);
        this.Instruction = Util.GetInstruction(tn);
        this.Id = 2;
        this.Name= "Bridge";
        this.Something = Util.GetSomething(tn);
    }

    public Bridge()
    {

    }

}
```

`Something` is another object:

```
[DataContract]
public class Something
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Number;
}
```

And `CaseGeneric` has all of this:

```
[DataContract]
public class CaseGeneric
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Instruction;
    [DataMember]
    public int Id;
    [DataMember]
    public string Name;
    [DataMember]
    public List<Something> Something;
}
```

Would anyone be able to help? Also please let me know if you need more information, I will be more than happy to add/edit anything or answer any questions. I thought that I might need to decorate my objects with `[KnownType(typeof(blah))]` I just dont know where and of which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to write a object in a list. Try changing
 `DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(CaseTreatment));` 
to 
`DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<CaseTreatment>));`